# should I create Public api based on the current internal api

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My project is having public website and Content Management System(CMS).
I am using Lambda and API Gateway for the api.
The CMS currently has an api GET request to get ALL the data from the table below.

“Banner” Table

attribute:
-id: string(primary key/partition key)
-title: string
-isActive: boolean
...

```
-----------------------------------------------
Id    isActive    title
1    true        title1
2    false        title2
3    true        title3
4    true        title4
----------------------------------------------
```

This is My lambda function: 
getBanner.js

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode = 0;

    const params = {
        TableName : "Banner",
    };

    try{
        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
        responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items);
        statusCode = 200
    }catch(err){
        statusCode = 403
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        body: responseBody
    }

    return response
}
```

I need an api to get all banners with isActive = true.

There are 2 approaches I can think of

1.Modify the existing lambda function

I can add something like below:

```
…
if(event.queryStringParameters.isActive === true){
     // add filter or query to get all result
}
...
```

But everyone is able to get all the data(including the results with isActive = false) if they do not use the queryStringParameters,
 which is what I want to avoid since the data with isActive = false should not be seen by the public.

2.Create new lambda function

This is probably the best way to protect the data.
But I have a lot of API encountering the same situation(having “inActive” attribute), it means I need to create a lot of public api.
Which method should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public API Gateway that points to the same Lambda functions, and in the API Gateway configuration have it always pass the `isActive=true` parameter so that users of the public API wouldn't be able to override that.

Comment: That means I should create another api in api gateway console?

Comment: Yes that's what "create another API Gateway" means.

Comment: Can you explain more about how to set API Gateway configuration? A lot of thanks