# How do 2 api in api gateway share same lambda function but different environment variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, api-design

I currently have an api called “cms-api”, which contains a dynamodb scan function in it.

getOrganization.js

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
    const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    let responseBody = "";

    const params = {
        TableName : "Organization"
    };

    try{
        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
    }catch(err){
        responseBody = `Unable to get Organization: ${err}`;
    }
}
```

“Organization” Table has below attributes

```
------------------------------------------
Id    isActive    name
1    true              tim
2    false            tom
3    true             ken
4    true            joe
------------------------------------------
```

Later, I create another api in api gateway called web-api,
I want to use the same lambda function getOrganization.js in my resource.
But the getOrganization.js should only return the data with isActive = true.

Is it possible? Or should I create a new lambda function every time?

Attached my consideration before.
[should I create Public api based on the current internal api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128462/should-i-create-public-api-based-on-the-current-internal-api/65129189#65129189)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you would consider using [stage variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stage-variables.html) in your API gateway. They allow you:

> You can also use stage variables to **pass configuration parameters to a Lambda function** through your mapping templates. For example, you might want to **reuse the same Lambda function** for multiple stages in your API, but the function should read data from a different Amazon DynamoDB table depending on which stage is being called. In the **mapping templates** that generate the request for the Lambda function, you can use stage variables to pass the table name to Lambda.

Comment: So u mean I don’t need to create new api actually?

Comment: @CCCC You can have two different stages in a single API. Each stage will use different values for stage variables which you can pass to a single function, as explained in the docs.